# Error ciphers laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

tengo un error con los ciphers en mi proyecto en laravel 7.
Ocurrio despues de intentar subir mi proyecto en heroku.
Me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En config/app tengo esta configuracion:

```
'cipher' => env('AES-256-CBC'),
```

Comment: Código como texto por favor así como el mensaje de error

Comment: Prueba [lo que aquí recomienda el usuario Andrew](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080)